# Is there a way to see the videos of the participants in Google Meet while sharing a Chrome tab?

Tags: google-meet

When I'm sharing a Chrome tab in Google Meet I can't see the videos of the participants. Is there a simple solution for this other than opening another browser or using another device?

Comment: Welcome to Web Applications Stack Exchange. Please explain what you mean by "Opening another browser will be resource demanding" and add more details about your case. We don't know how many devices you have if you can connect additional screens and the resource limitations.